# Mostrar datos según el option que elija php

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy intentando que tras seleccionar una opción del select, reciba los datos de esa opción trayendolos de la base de datos. He modificado el código anterior ya que no había una base hecha. Ahora mismo me está fallando, ya que me está mostrando mal o no muestra nada en lo que selecciono.

Ahora mismo no veo el fallo por el cual debe estar fallando a la hora de hacer bien el select y traer los datos.

```
    <?php
require_once 'php/conexion.php';
   if (isset($_POST['cod'])) $codigo = $_POST['cod']; 


?>
<!DOCTYPE >
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Tarea 03 - Iván Incera Setien </title>

        <link href="css/estilos.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    </head>
    <body>
       <h1>Listado de productos de una familia</h1> 
       <form id="form_listado" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>" method="post">
   <span>Familia: </span>
   <select name="cod">
      <?php 
      $stmt = "SELECT cod, nombre FROM familia";
      $resultado = $pdo->query($stmt); 
      $resultado ->fetch();
      $row = $resultado ->fetch();
      while($row != null){
         ?>
         <option value="<?php echo $row['cod']?>"> <?php echo $row['nombre']?></option>
         <?php
         $row = $resultado->fetch();
      }
         ?>
         </select>
         <input type="submit" value="Mostrar" name="Enviar">
       </form>

       <div>
          <h2>Productos de la familia</h2>
         <?php 
          $stmt2 = "SELECT producto.* FROM producto INNER JOIN familia ON producto.familia=familia.cod
          WHERE familia.cod='$codigo'";
          $resultado2 = $pdo->query($stmt2);
          $row2 = $resultado2 ->fetch();
          $codPro=$row2['cod'];
          $nombre=$row2['nombre'];
          $nombre_corto=$row2['nombre_corto'];
          $descripcion=$row2['descripcion'];
          $pvp=$row2['PVP'];
         while($row2 != null){
            ?>
            <form id="form" action="php/editar.php" method="post">
            <input type="hidden" name="cod" value="<?php echo $codPro?>">
            <p>Producto <b><?php echo $nombre_corto?></b> PVP: <b><?php echo $pvp?></b> € <input type="submit" value="Editar" name="edit"></p>

         </form>
         <?php
         $row2=$resultado2->fetch();
         }
         ?>
       </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: No es lo mismo, son problemas distintos

Comment: Tienes razón, al ver el exactamente el mismo código me llevó a confusión. Mis disculpas ^^

Comment: No te preocupes, no problem :)

Comment: No es clara tu pregunta. Lo que parece que necesitas es hacer un `JOIN` entre las tablas. ¿Cuál es el fallo o problema que experimentas actualmente? ¿Qué hace el código?  ¿Qué debería hacer?